# cannot open SELECT query as cursor

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to construct a string from a table.  I need to construct a string from each row and then concatenate these strings (with an appropriate separator) together.  In a simple example the select produces a table with 3 rows; however, I get the message above.

Can anyone help?  Thanks

```
for mFiles in 
    select url || pth || basename || '/' || basename || '.2.' || clientname into fName from files 
       where ( userId is null or uid != userId ) and (url is not null) and (pth is not null) 
          order by RANDOM() limit nImages LOOP
       res := res || fName || '|';
     RAISE NOTICE ' fName: % ' , fName;
   END LOOP;
```

Comment: What's your PostgreSQL version? Odd issue. I haven't looked into it or tested, but if I had to make a wild guess I'd be wondering if the `limit` clause was the issue...

Answer (score 2):

The problem was 'into fName'.  Replacing this by 'as fName' and writing 
    res:= res || mFiles.fName || '|';

fixed the problem.  Don't understand why exactly but ...

Answer (score 0):

Following from Craig Ringer's suggestion, what if you remove the `limit` clause and instead break out of the loop with code like this (which would both test whether `limit` is the culprit and provide a good workaround):

```
idx := 1
for mFiles in 
    select url || pth || basename || '/' || basename || '.2.' || clientname into fName from files 
    where ( userId is null or uid != userId ) and (url is not null) and (pth is not null) 
    order by RANDOM()
    LOOP
        res := res || fName || '|';
        RAISE NOTICE ' fName: % ' , fName;

        IF idx = nImages THEN
            EXIT
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
```

With the addition of declaring `idx` in the appropriate section higher up in the code.